# Alamofire JSON Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1aade0750) to 'NSNumber' (0x1aadec4b0)

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire to get Data JSON from URL in response

```
{{
“lon”:123.4567890,
“lat”:12.3456789
}}
```

I use code for add data to Array from JSON Data

```
lat.append(JSON[0]["lat"] as! Float64)
```

But It response

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1aade0750) to 'NSNumber' (0x1aadec4b0).
```

I'll try to change type of lat variable from Float64 to String but it failed

Thanks for all your Helps

Comment: how did u initialize JSON array?

Comment: We see `JSON[0]`: you take the first element from an array, but the JSON response you're showing has no array... In fact, this JSON is invalid: `{{ }}`